# Tensorflow installation killed on AWS ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, tensorflow2.0, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to use `AWS EC2` instance for to test my `ML` project. During the package installation process of `TensorFlow` getting kills every time.

I'm using AWS trial EC2 `t2.micro` type instance for my testing purposes.

- Type: `t2.micro`
- vCPUs: `1`
- Memory: `1GB`
- Os: `Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type`

[image]

Is there any soulutions for this?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58760516/setting-up-aws-ec2-instance-with-tensorflow-2-0-ami-versus-building-it-yourse) thread?

Comment: yeah I read it before but It's for gpu support and also required docker.

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem, and I finally fixed it by doing the following:

- Using free tier instance, but with 25 Gib of hard disk storage (currently, free tier covers up to 30 Gib without extra cost)
- Install tensorflow by running `pip install tensorflow-cpu` instead of just `pip install tensorflow`

Answer (score 4):

Use `--no-cache-dir` argument with the pip installation command to resolve the tensorflow installation killed issue in aws ec2 instances.

```
pip3 install tensorflow --no-cache-dir
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It can be fixed with the following command:

```
pip install tensorflow-cpu
```

instead of just:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to state an exact memory requirement for installing Tensorflow and its dependencies, but most likely this instance size is too small. You could verify it works with a larger instance and/or try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63411128/how-much-space-is-necessary-to-install-tensorflow)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I followed instructions on your link and then its says "ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device". So seems like the instance is too small.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the issues is I have not enough space in my EC2 instance. By running this command.

```
sudo pip install --cache-dir=/data/jimit/ --build /data/jimit/ tensorflow TMPDIR==/data/jimit/
```

It outputs below error.

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63411128/how-much-space-is-necessary-to-install-tensorflow). Cradits to @bigmac

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and
`pip install tensorflow-cpu`
was also getting killed.
I used
`pip3 install tensorflow-cpu --no-cache-dir`
which worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me, running:

```bash
pip3 install tensorflow-cpu --no-cache-dir
```

Fixed it on the free tier