# failed to install tensorflow on a EC2 instance Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, amazon-ec2

I have a flask application that I would like to run it on an EC2 instance and TensorFlow is needed cause it is image classification. However, after the necessary updates and upgrades, I try to install TensorFlow but after the progress bar completes, I don't see the successfully installed tensorflow==2.7.0. Images are attached, is there any reason for why it is not letting me install TensorFlow, or does the instance have limitations that won't let me install it. Please help and thanks in advance.

[installing the TensorFlow on the EC2 instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJDIW.png)

Comment: Out of superstition, have you tried `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`?  I notice that `keras` was installed as root, but you're installing tensorflow as a user.  That shouldn't matter, but it's something to note.

Comment: Look at the ETA of the TensorFlow installation, it says Killed, you somehow ran out of resources while installing tensorflow, so it was not actually installed.

Comment: @TimRoberts, I installed Keras using pip but TensorFlow does not work, I tried with pip install --upgrade TensorFlow, and I also tried it with specifying the version number, nothing seemed to work.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, yes I saw that when I posted this question, but do you know why that could be the reason, could it be related to the instance type that I selected prior to initiating the instance? (because I am using the free tier that they offer t2.micro). Do you have any idea how I can make sure that it does not get killed before it completes the installation?

Comment: I found out that the storage size of the hard disk matters, after increasing it to 30 GB, I could install it using pip install tensorflow-cpu [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67381812/tensorflow-installation-killed-on-aws-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 0):

- Increase the storage on the hard disk (30 GB on my case_
- pip install tensorflow-cpu

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67381812/tensorflow-installation-killed-on-aws-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error and apparently the storage was not the reason. I tried using large instance with large memory and I was able to install tensorflow in the anaconda environment successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason AWS does not allow for installing Tensorflow directly. for me it works when using:

pip3 install tensorflow==2.7.0 --no-cache-dir